# How to filter the notifications by the class that sent them

Tags: android, android-notifications, notification-listener

I am using NotificationListenerService in my App which is called "NLS_APP" and in each method in the NotificationListnerService class I print some logs inidicating which method or callback is being called
. As for testing, I create another App that does noting except sending a notification.when I ran the test App, I fond that the NLS_APP is receiving the notifications from the test App.

is there any way to filter the notifications so that to receive only the notifications sent from within my App "NLS_App" "the app that uses NotificationsListenerService? In other words, i do want my App "NLS_App" to receive notifications from any other Apps.

Comment: Try to send Payload with pushnotification using that payload you can easily identified which app notification you want to show and which not.

Comment: send an unique parameter in notification data to identify your app.

Comment: @AndyDeveloper how to send a payload please?!! do you mean in onStartCommand??

Comment: @UsmanRana would you please tell me how to send notification data

Comment: with notification some extras are received like title,message etc. you can send an additional param as well that will represent your app.

Comment: @user2121 here is the reference for payload [send from FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options).

Comment: Payload send the notification with json format and you need to parse that json format in onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) where you can filter your notificaiton.